# Mac OS X weird new popup

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, osx-mavericks

In intellij after upgrade? Or perhaps a coincidence 
Anynbody seen this?!

[weird popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFpyQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, it was an April fool's joke. After April the First it shouldn't appear anymore.